# R：split dataframe into list more efficiently

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many rows，one column is facor，I want to split the dataframe into list according to the factor column，How can I do it more efficiently？

```
library(microbenchmark)

size <- 1e7
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = factor(sample(100, size, replace = TRUE)),
  V2 = rnorm(size), v3 = rnorm(size)
)


microbenchmark(dfs <- split(df, df$V1))
```

Comment: I want to split a dataframe，but what is splitted in the two answer is a vector

Comment: Look also at this post: [R - split large dataframe into list in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312300/r-split-large-dataframe-into-list-in-parallel). Use `by` or `split` without factors.